# how to retain the decimal part in redshift when the decimal part is only having 0

Tags: amazon-redshift, multiplication

In my code we are using a multiplication as (180.00*60.00).
Ideally since both the numbers are of decimal type I'm expecting my answer to be also in decimal. But in redshift I observed that this equation is resulting only to Integer.
Basically when this multiplication happens I want the answer as 10800.0000 and not 10800.
how to achieve this in Redshift. I tried putting the cast to whole expression and also even to individual expression but still I'm getting the answer only in Integer.
any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you are asking why Redshift isn't inferring that the string "180.00*60.00" as being the multiplication of 2 values in decimal type, yes?  If correct you just need to cast the input values for the multiplication.  For example:

```
select 180.00::decimal(6,2) * 60.00::decimal(6,2) ;
```

It also looks like you want the result to have 4 significant digits so you may want to cast to decimal(8,4).

If I've missed the point of your question please clarify.

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you for your answer. You were on point. My apologies for reverting very late on this.
I use dbeaver tool for connecting redshift. It seems some tool setting as to be changed to  view the result with decimal digits. Because I had tried casting the numbers and even If I run your statement in dbeaver it is giving me 10,800 as answer.
but your answer is right. thank you again for the reply Bill Weiner.